# Git pull does not update local repo (from GitLab)

Tags: git, gitlab

While trying to pull from a remote GitLab repository I am getting:

```
$ git pull origin master
From ######
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

But checking the local and the remote repos there is clearly a difference. Why would this be happening and how could I update to local repo to represent what is on the remote repo?

Additional Info, if I do `git status`, I get the following:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   ######.py

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

And doing `git diff` shows me a long list of differences.

Answer (score 1):

The modified file is not tracked in your local repo. You need to `git add ######.py` just as the message output says.

More info can be found here [git add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)

Comment: It has to be tracked because I pushed it up from the local repo initially, and when I `git ls-tree -r master --name-only`, it is there in the output

Comment: According to the message that is not the case. What happens if you do as the message says and add the file?

Comment: Just tried that, I'm getting `warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ######.py.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory`

Comment: That just means that line endings will be changed to CRLF. Like the message says.

Comment: Yea I did `git add ######.py` and `git pull origin master` but it's still not pulling the update from the remote repo

Comment: Is `######.py` already in the remote repo? Can you verify that? Edit: I can see that it is as you wrote that in the first comment. What happens if you push and then pull?